# Override Webpack 4.25.1's use of Uglify in production mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

According to the documentation, when `module.exports = { mode: 'production' }`, it uses UglifyJS by default:

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/#mode-production

As I understand it, this library has been abandoned and is "full of bugs". `terser` is recommended to be used instead:

https://github.com/terser-js/terser

How do I override the default use of `mode: 'production'` for this particular plug? Is it sufficient to just add `terser` to `plugins: []`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the answer in the documentation:

**optimization.minimzer**

> Allows you to override the default minimizer by providing a different one or more customized UglifyjsWebpackPlugin instances.

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({ /* your config */ })
    ]
  }
};
```

You'd just replace all of the `UglifyJsPlugin` stuff with `terser`:

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()]
  }
};
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimization-minimizer